# Action doesn't create a cookie when its called by external API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say we have code as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AdvanceTokenCallback(string apiToken)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("Token", apiToken, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
        {
            Path = "/",
            Expires = _tokenCookieExpirationTime
        });
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateWorkItem));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateWorkItem()
    {
        string token = Request.Cookies["Token"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

When the action `AdvanceTokenCallback` is called from external API the `token` variable in the `CreateWorkItem` action becomes a `null`.
However in a case when I create a "bridge" action and move the logic which creates the cookie there, then the `token` located in CreateWorkItem contains a value which is something that I expected.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AdvanceTokenCallback(string apiToken)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(BridgeRedirect), new { apiToken });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult BridgeRedirect(string apiToken)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("Token", apiToken, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
        {
            Path = "/",
            Expires = _tokenCookieExpirationTime
        });
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateWorkItem));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateWorkItem()
    {
        string token = Request.Cookies["Token"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

Any idea why does it happen and is there a possibility to avoid having this extra `BridgeRedirect` action with extra redirect?

Comment: We need to see your client code.

Comment: There is no client code. The 3rd party app is calling the AdvanceTokenCallback. You can assume that there is no access to the code of this 3rd party app.

Comment: "called from external API" - that external API is your client. The code *there* is most likely the issue.

Comment: you can treat "external API" as an authentication service e.g. AAD or Amazon Cognito which returns a token(send a callback) after I type the proper credentials.

Comment: Usually, an "exteneral API" like AAD should request HTTP GET method for redirectURI. why you use POST action? I leverage a post form to call the action which set cookie and redirect to another action, which works fine.  Do you have any additional configuration in `UseCookiePolicy` in `startup.cs`?

Comment: You may be right. I gave AAD only as an example to show what I mean but in fact, I'm using some other service created by my company and they are using POST instead of GET. I didn't add any configuration of the `UseCookiePolicy` to the `Startup.cs`. Im open for any suggestion.

Comment: You can hava a Fiddler trace of your broken and owrkding scenarios and compare them. Cause there is nothing obvious to me why it doesn't work,

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I think there must be something wrong with the call which comes from this external service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that code works and do not on different machines and different environments when I run the app on localhost.
After I set the `IsEssential` attribute to true when creating the Cookie everything works fine.
From the Microsoft documentation:

> IsEssential -  Indicates if this cookie is essential for the
>   application to function correctly. If true then consent policy checks
>   may be bypassed. The default value is false.

So the solution in my case is to just create a cookie like this:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("Token", apiToken, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
{
    IsEssential = true,
    Expires = _tokenCookieExpirationTime
});
```

Using this way I don't need having this extra `BridgeRedirect` anymore.